# Сократить код в python

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня таких лиг больше 20:

```py
elif data == "esp_football_league":
    teams = [
    (emoji.emojize(":white_circle:") + " Реал Мадрид", "Real_Madrid"),
    (emoji.emojize(":red_circle:") + " Барселона", "Barcelona"),
    (emoji.emojize(":red_circle:") + " Атлетико", "Atletico"),
    (emoji.emojize(":red_circle:") + " Севилья", "Sevilla"),
    ...
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for team, team_cd in teams:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
    await callback.message.edit_text(emoji.emojize(":downwards_button: Выберите команду:"), reply_markup=markup)

elif data == "ukr_football_league":
    teams = [
    (emoji.emojize(":orange_circle:") + " Шахтер Донецк", "Shakhtar_Donetsk"),
    (emoji.emojize(":white_circle:") + " Динамо Киев", "Dynamo_Kyiv"),
    (emoji.emojize(":blue_circle:") + " Днепр-1", "Dnipro-1"),
    (emoji.emojize(":black_circle:") + " Заря", "Zorya"),
    ...
    ]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for team, team_cd in teams:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
    await callback.message.edit_text(emoji.emojize(":downwards_button: Выберите команду:"), reply_markup=markup)
```

И везде повторяется блок кода:

```py
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
for team, team_cd in teams:
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
await callback.message.edit_text(emoji.emojize(":downwards_button: Выберите команду:"), reply_markup=markup)
```

Отсюда вопрос: как это все сократить с помощью функции, чтоб каждый раз не писать один повторяющийся блок?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместите данные в словарь:

```
teams_data = \
{
    "esp_football_league":
    [
    (emoji.emojize(":white_circle:") + " Реал Мадрид", "Real_Madrid"),
    (emoji.emojize(":red_circle:") + " Барселона", "Barcelona"),
    (emoji.emojize(":red_circle:") + " Атлетико", "Atletico"),
    (emoji.emojize(":red_circle:") + " Севилья", "Sevilla"),
    ...
    ],
    "ukr_football_league":
    [
    (emoji.emojize(":orange_circle:") + " Шахтер Донецк", "Shakhtar_Donetsk"),
    (emoji.emojize(":white_circle:") + " Динамо Киев", "Dynamo_Kyiv"),
    (emoji.emojize(":blue_circle:") + " Днепр-1", "Dnipro-1"),
    (emoji.emojize(":black_circle:") + " Заря", "Zorya"),
    ...
    ],
    ...
}

teams = teams_data.get(data)
# проверяем, есть ли такой ключ в словаре
if teams:
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for team, team_cd in teams:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
    await callback.message.edit_text(emoji.emojize(":downwards_button: Выберите команду:"), reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: объективно хорошо использовать словарь для всех данных. Если данные велики, то можно и БД использовать. Не в курсе, правда, на счет дружбы с ботами телеграма, совсем профан(

Answer (score 3):

если глубоко не копать, то засунуть этот код в функцию

```py
async def your_func(teams):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    for team, team_cd in teams:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(team, callback_data=f"prefix:{team_cd}"))
    await callback.message.edit_text(emoji.emojize(":downwards_button: Выберите команду:"), reply_markup=markup)
```

А далее вызывать ее

```py
elif data == "ukr_football_league":
    teams = [
    (emoji.emojize(":orange_circle:") + " Шахтер Донецк", "Shakhtar_Donetsk"),
    (emoji.emojize(":white_circle:") + " Динамо Киев", "Dynamo_Kyiv"),
    (emoji.emojize(":blue_circle:") + " Днепр-1", "Dnipro-1"),
    (emoji.emojize(":black_circle:") + " Заря", "Zorya"),
    ...
    ]
    await your_func(teams)
```

и так везде

Comment: спасибо за ответ, только выскочила ошибка: ```RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback```. Помогло: ```await my_func(teams)```.

Comment: @ВладиславГончаров забыл указать, поправил ответ)

Answer (score 2):

```
# определение функции
def func(*args): 
     return args

# вызов функции
func(1, 2, 3, 'abc')
```

Comment: может все же дать ответ относительно того кода, который представлен в вопросе:)? плюс мой, но все же мысль верна)

Comment: @Dmitry такой ответ уже есть выше. Я лишь попытался предоставить упрощенный пример, который показывает что такое функция. Зная то как создаются функции, человек без труда сможет выделить общую часть. Вы не согласны с этим?